# Handling missing properties in API responses

Tags: javascript, rest, validation, single-page-application

How should I handle missing properties in an API response from the backend?

I have a React app and I fetch some data from backend. Then I use this data to render some elements and also to handle some actions based on values in that response. But it may happen that some values are missing.
Should then I always validate API responses in a way that it assigns default values to missing properties like:

```
import { get } from 'lodash'


const { data } = await axios.get(...);

const dataForFrontend = {
  id: get(data, 'id', 'N/A'),
  name: get(data, 'name', 'N/A'),
  lastName: get(data, 'lastName', 'N/A'),
  email: {
    address: get(data, 'email.address', 'N/A'),
    active: get(data, 'email.active', false),
  }
}
```

(if `data` had no `email` field and I used it right away then fronted app would most likely break with "cannot read property `address` of undefined".)

...or maybe I should just use `data` right away and assume it's valid otherwise that would mean backend is broken and by assigning default values I just swept the problem under the carpet (I mean that it would come up later with some other error about trying for example to multiply 100 with `N/A`)?

I would like to know correct approach to this - validate or assume it has to be valid?

Answer (score 2):

How to handle this entirely depends on your business needs and the amount of effort you're willing to put in to handling these cases.

I agree it would be a bad idea to return `N/A` if your front-end app is likely to try to multiply that string by 100.

**Most work, best user experience**

It sounds like you have otherwise legitimate entries in your database or API that may have missing properties.  In this case, you would probably do best to follow a policy of "graceful degradation", where your front end logic is prepared to deal with the missing properties, perhaps requiring those missing properties to be filled in before any further work can be done with that record.

**Less work, still communicating a problem to the user**

The next best option would probably be to validate the incoming data immediately and fail the request with a thrown error that gets presented to the user with useful information.

**The worst way**

Of all three of these options, papering over an incomplete record seems the worst option.